# Is it allowed to ask for general feedback on arrangement?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

There is a SE site called [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) that is a splendid complement to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). In the latter one you typically ask questions that has a clear answer. But on Codereview a question is typically like [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/201399/133688):

> I've written a very simple linked list based stack implementation and was wondering if this is the standard way to do it in C.
>
> ```
> typedef struct Node {
>     int value;
>     struct Node *prev;
> } Node;
>
> Node * push(Node *top, int value) {
>     Node *node = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
>     node->value = value;
>     node->prev = top;
>     return node;
> }
>
> Node * pop(Node *top, int *val_addr) {
>     *val_addr = top->value;
>     Node *new_top = top->prev;
>     free(top);
>     return new_top;
> }
>
> int is_empty(Node *top) {
>     return top == NULL;
> }
> ```
>
> Before deciding to post on code review I decided to check google for stack implementations to see if mine was okay. But most of the decent sources that I checked used an array implementation. I was wondering in what situation is it better to use a dynamic array based stack?

Is this allowed here? I'm arranging music from time to time and it would be wonderful to get feedback. Spontaneously I feel that it would be better with a separate SE site for that, but at the moment I think this site has to few users to motivate a spinoff.

So is this allowed, and if no, should it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure we don't do that in the main site but you can ask for comments and feedback on chat.

Answer (score 3):

It is currently not allowed for both being too broad and being primary option based and also has issues related to the questions addressed here [Questions pertaining Performance reviewal](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/730/questions-pertaining-performance-reviewal).

That being said, there are a lot of good reviewing other's works can do for both the person asking and the people answering. This site currently is not designed to handle them especially when our main topics are object and answerable music related question. I highly recommend you take it to our chat and ask there as several of our members will see it and be able to give you some feedback.

If we drum up enough interest we can talk about doing an SE devoted to it. I also don't see that happening any time soon, but one can hope.